# TColorProperty Delphi Berlin 10.1.2?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to convert a component from Delphi 7 to Delphi Berlin (flatstyle component: https://sourceforge.net/projects/flatstyle/)

After many changes in the source, i´m stuck in TColorPorperty

See below:

```
type
  TRxColorProperty = class(TColorProperty)
  public
    function GetValue: string; override;
    procedure GetValues (Proc: TGetStrProc); override;
    procedure SetValue (const Value: string); override;
```

In Delphi 7, this class is in  VCLEditors unit. But i can´t find in Delphi Berlin.

Someone can tell me where to find her in Delphi Berlin?

Comment: In Delphi 10.1 Berlin `VCLEditors.pas` unit  is located in `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\source\ToolsAPI`. The `TColorProperty` class is present. I don't have update 2 installed, so can't verify the location in ud2.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: The location of `VCLEditors` has not changed (`$(BDS)\source\ToolsAPI`) since D6, when `DsgnIntf` was broken up and `VCLEditors` was introduced.  And `TColorProperty` has not been moved out of `VCLEditors`, AFAIK.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: updates in a given version are non-breaking, so `TColorProperty` would not be movable to another unit (if ever done) until the next major version.  So it has to still exist in `VCLEditors` in Update 2.

Comment: Yes, @Remy Thanks for the added clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not what you asked (due to my low reputation points I could not comment this) but I'm using the same component on RAD studio Seattle. It is not tested on Berlin though.

Here is the 
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/c336i59ozey4yue/FLATStyle.rar).
 Use it on your own risks.

The same installation steps in delphi 7 are applied her.

Regards; Nasreddine.

Answer (score 4):

The `TFlatDesignRegister.pas` unit is using the outdated `DsgnIntf` unit.  That unit was removed and refactored **in Delphi 6** into various new units (`DesignIntf`, `DesignEditors`, `VCLEditors`, etc).  There is no way the code would compile as-is **in Delphi 7**.  Any changes needed to make it compile in Delphi 7 still apply in 10.1 Berlin.

In Delphi 6 onwards, `TColorProperty` is in the `VCLEditors` unit, which still exists in 10.1 Berlin.

That being said, the runtime code (components, etc) and the design-time code (editors, IDE registrations, etc) **must** be separated into different packages, where the design-time package requires the runtime package and the `DesignIDE` package.  The package files included in the download are NOT setup that way.  Old IDE versions did not enforce that, but modern IDE versions do.  So make sure you are making that change when creating new packages for 10.1 Berlin.